# ASP.NET Web API as Service with Custom Route - get 405 method not allowed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I've created an ASP.NET Web API Project and I don't want to use the Verbs like "PUT", "GET", .... so I've created my Own Route in the WebApiConfig.

```
Public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "DefaultApi",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );
}
```

Then I've Created an very Simple ApiController

```
public class EWebApiController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage ByEntryFilter(long? id)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Test string");
        return response;
  }
}
```

Now I can start my Webapplication to host my WebApi.

Then I've Created an simple Console Application to call my WebApi Function

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    //byte[] data = webClient.DownloadData("http://localhost:51762/api/EWebApi/ByEntryFilter/2/");
    //string date = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:51762/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/EWebApi/ByEntryFilter/2").Result;  // Blocking call!
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
           //Never Reached because auf 405 method not allowed
    }
}
```

And here I Allways get the 405 method not allowed Error. With both the WebClient and the HttpClient Calls.

When I am using the Default ApiRoute and Using the GET, ... Verbs everything works.

Thats no "WebDav" Problem, thats not installed and in my Web.Config I've Removed it with "" ....

When I am Using my Route with local jQuery AJAX Calls on a Website inside my WebProject then my ApiRoute is also working like a charm and no 405 Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using **Restful** pattern affix GET, PUT, DELETE, POST ... you must provide `Attributes` to tell the action what **HTTP** method this will be:

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "HEAD")]
public HttpResponseMessage ByEntryFilter(long? id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Test string");
    return response;
}
```

Or

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("ByEntryFilter")]
public HttpResponseMessage ByEntryFilter(long? id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Test string");
    return response;
}
```

More information here: [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)